# Laravel: Routing Not Working

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I googled the matter and there are many who've had this issue, but each had his own very unique case, and at the end nothing I read helped me.

I just finished installing Laravel with xampp, hopefully properly. Apache and MySQL are running.

I'm starting with the very first tutorial:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick#routing

My app root is:
http://localhost/Laravel/tests/app/

The hello.php file is working for me, I even tested some php code (plain not laravel) and it worked:
http://localhost/Laravel/tests/app/views/hello.php

As the tutorial instructed, I added in app/routes.php:

```
Route::get('users', function()
{
    return 'Users!';
});
```

but when I try to access

http://localhost/Laravel/tests/app/views/users

I get "Object not found!" while I should be getting the text "Users!"

Comment: Try http://localhost/Laravel/tests/app/users

Comment: Since you're not using Homestead or `php artisan serve`, you need to set up pretty URLs per http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls

Comment: Robo Robok - same, getting "Object not found!"

Comment: Your file structure is very confusing.  Where is your `public` folder?

Comment: Exactly where Yoel Monzon wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not route correct, test with: http://localhot/Laravel/tests/public/users